# Poisson distribution for $P(X \geq 2)$

Tags: probability

Suppose that X is a random variable having the Poisson distribution with mean Lambda, and such that $P(X = 2) = P(X = 4)$, find $\lambda$, and $P(X \geq 2)$

So I found that $ \lambda= \sqrt{12}$, but I'm not sure how to find $P(X\geq2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $P(X \geq 2)=1-P(X<2)=1-P(0)-P(1)$

Comment: Ahhhh, I see thank you very much